# Any way to create a 3 LED chaser with only a 555 IC?

Tags: led, 555

I've seen single and dual blinking circuits, but wanted to know if there was some easy way to squeeze in a third? I don't have a 4017 IC at the moment, unfortunately.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't get at the 555's third state, not that you would be able to make a chaser if you had it anyways. Although the 555 does have everything you'd otherwise need.

Comment: I guess it might work with 3 555's configured as monostable multivibrators in a circle. Triggering the next stage requires some careful thought.

Answer (score 1):

This could be done, but it would be a lot simpler to just get a shift register IC or small microcontroller. The schematic would be quite large, and I'm not going to design it for you. Here is a block diagram and some things to research.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frvwZs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

First, a square wave is fed into an integrator to generate a triangle wave. The triangle wave is sent to 3 window comparators. You can adjust the windows and square wave frequency to get the desired chase.

Comment: You can use the signal at pin 2 or 6 (both connected to the cap for the astable mode) of the 555 in place of the integrator. Also you can use only 2 comparators without the need of the window comparison by changing the LEDs configuration. In the end you just need the 555 and a double comparator.

Comment: [Like this](http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/10/1425611442-untitled.png) for the comparator.

Comment: @Biduleohm that may not function the way the op expects

Comment: From what he describes it's OK. The sequence would be: 1 2 3 2 1 2 3 2 1 2 3 2 1...

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can and no you do not need comparators. You need to feed the output into a ring counter, which can be built out  of transistors, resistors and capacitors. Search in Google for "ring counter using transistors".

Example result:

[Example result: http://www.tradeofic.com/uploadfile/ic-circuit/2009713234814285.gif](http://www.tradeofic.com/uploadfile/ic-circuit/2009713234814285.gif)

Comment: I'll take my chances with some comparator ICs before trying to build that. Ewwwwwww

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you could do away with the 555 chip all together. Then get a set of chaser LED Christmas lights and hack it to support the LEDs you want to blink instead of the the string lights.